# Datatable Sorting From A Custom Number Sequence

Tags: vb.net

My datatable has a field that has values like so..

```
0000006685-001
0000006685-002
0000006713-001
0000006714-002
0000006713-002
0000006697-002
```

I want the datatable to be re-ordered by this field so the numbers on the left of the hyphen go in order, followed by the corresponding sequence in order. So the above example data would be ordered like..

```
0000006685-001
0000006685-002
0000006697-002
0000006713-001
0000006713-002
0000006714-002
```

Comment: Is each line 1 field or 2 fields?  If it's 1 field normal sorting should do what you want.  If it's 2 fields you could use `OrderBy/ThenBy` when you load the data

Comment: each line is one field. Can you post an example?

Comment: A lot will depend on what structure you're holding/viewing your data, also what type of project you're making.

Comment: A datatable has a field with these values based on this field I want to order the records

Comment: In the string you use to load the data add an OrderBy clause with that field as a parameter.  It's hard to give good examples without some code to go by, since there's more than one way to accomplish what you're doing.  And like I mentioned the type of project also plays a part, winform, webform, wpf, etc. all have their own quirks when it comes to this sort of thing.

Comment: Any example will do. My code is too complex too display it

Comment: All that's really needed is the routine that loads your datatable, specifically the SQL string.

Comment: the datable is loaded from a dll. I have no access to an sql string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Dim dv As New DataView(parsedDataset.Tables("Detail"))
        dv.Sort = "the field"
 Dim dt As DataTable = dv.ToTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, most probably, through the Select method then the CopyToTable method

```
dt = dt.Select("", "ColumnName ASC").CopyToDataTable
```

Replace `ColumnName` with the name of the column for that field.